# Where to find regions

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

Now I have created regions.
Where I can find it to put block in it.
 I have search module to put so that I can render it.

Comment: Hi, that makes absolutely no sense I'm afraid. Please take the time to describe your problem properly, including how you've tried to solve the problem, what went wrong, etc, so what you're asking can be understood properly, and your question becomes useful to the Q+A repository here. Once you've done that please flag for re-opening. Thanks

Comment: oh sorry its block. I am good with html and php but new to drupal

Comment: and thank you @Clive... It solved my problem.... I was searching it in Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put *module* in region. You put **blocks** in regions.

Go to http://example.com/admin/structure/block to see regions and blocks assigned to them. Of course substitute *example.com* with your real domain name.